# How to write and read many single and multi lines String

Tags: java, file

I have a list of strings

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I want to store single-line and multi-line strings in this list,
then save them to a file

```
public static void storeToFile(List<String> strings, String fileName) {}
public static List<String> fromFile(String fileName) {}
```

chcę abym mógł uzyskać nową eg.

```
strings.add("something");
strings.add("I\nlike\nto\nride\nhorses\nsometimes");
strings.add("its ok");
```

I am looking for an idea on how to separate these strings in the file, I exclude the use of a separator, because what if the user enters a string of characters that is also a separator, I also exclude counting the lines before the string. I know JSON can do the trick, but is there any other option?

Comment: If you want to store "multi-line strings" in a file where they would actually occupy multiple lines, then you need to define a *delimiter* that will indicate when each string ends. Then you can consistently parse the text in the file into multi-line strings.

Comment: The easiest and most flexible way to serialize data in a text-readable way is via JSON or XML. And the easiest way to do this is via a library, such as GSON or Jackson. This is what I recommend that you do.

Comment: @h0r53 I know how to do it best so that it doesn't conflict with the strings in the file, as I mentioned

Comment: Use the _String#split_ method to divide the values, then place the values on a single line, each within quotes, escaped, and delimited.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store both single-line and multi-line strings in a file without using a separator and without precomputing the number of lines, you can use a format that encodes the length of each string before the string itself. One way to achieve this is by using a binary format, where each string is preceded by a fixed-size integer representing its length in bytes.

Here's an example of how you can implement the storeToFile and fromFile methods using this approach:

```
public static void storeToFile(List<String> strings, String fileName) {
    try (DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
        for (String str : strings) {
            byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
            int length = bytes.length;
            outputStream.writeInt(length); // Write the length
            outputStream.write(bytes);     // Write the bytes
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static List<String> fromFile(String fileName) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    try (DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
        while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
            int length = inputStream.readInt(); // Read the length
            byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
            inputStream.readFully(bytes);       // Read the bytes
            String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
            strings.add(str);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strings;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("something");
    strings.add("I\nlike\nto\nride\nhorses\nsometimes");
    strings.add("its ok");

    storeToFile(strings, "strings.dat");

    List<String> loadedStrings = fromFile("strings.dat");
    for (String str : loadedStrings) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

In this example, each string is stored as a series of bytes, with its length encoded as an integer before the string. This approach ensures that you can correctly separate the strings regardless of their content, including newlines or other characters that could be used as separators.

Comment: There is [DataInputStream::readUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF--) and [DataOutputStream::writeUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-) so your example can be changed to: 1) write number of items 2) write items. You could probably avoiding the step (1) while reading with the available() loop.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, using a delimiter for the Strings is an option – but why?

What about escaping the line feeds in the multiline Strings?

```
try( final var output = new PrintStream( file ) )
{
  for( final var string : strings )
  {
    output.println( string.replace( "\n", "\\n" ) );
    // If your string contains backslashes, try this instead:
    // output.println( string.replace( "\\", "\\\\" ).replace( "\n", "\\n" ) );    
  }
}
```

(Originally, the code was using `String#replaceAll` but as @erickson pointed out in their comment, this is using a Regex and will not work as expected)

Reading them is even simpler:

```
final List<String> strings = Files.lines( file.toPath )
  .map( String::translateEscapes )
  .toList();
```

Or what about using Base64 to store the strings in the file?

As usualy, I omitted the required error handling.

Comment: This actually corrupts the string by removing the desired line breaks. That's why I suggested joining the strings "manually."

Comment: @erickson – Explain that, please!

Comment: The escape sequence "\ {end-of-line}" is discarded by `translateEscapes()`. (Because in a multi-line string literal, `\ EOL` is a continuation of the string.)

Comment: @erickson – Confessed! But the question is about *multi-line* strings, not about *multi-line string* ***literals***! See the original question!

Comment: Right. You are using a method, `translateEscapes()`, that was designed for processing Java source code in some other context, and it's not doing what you want. The question is about preserving line breaks in a string. Your approach strips them from the string.

Comment: @erickson – The question is about storing strings in a file with preserving the line breaks *when reading them back*. Nothing was said on how the file format has to look like or if the strings in the file has to be readable.

Comment: I misunderstood the escape sequence you are using for linefeeds. You are trying to replace linefeed with backlash and a lowercase "n"; I read it as a backslash and a linefeed, which `translateEscapes()` would discard. You do have a problem in your `replaceAll()` calls though; they take regexes and all the slashes have to be doubled again.

Comment: To be clear, `string.replaceAll("\n", "\\n")` changes linefeeds to the letter "n" with no preceding backslash. "\\" isn't a valid regex, and the replacement text "\\\\" yields a single backslash, not two.

Comment: As always, I mix up `String#replace` and `String#replaceAll` – I corrected it in the answer …

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the default delimiter for textual data is the newline character. Since you want the newline character to be included in your representation of an individual string, you could use a new delimiter to achieve this.

For example, you are interested in storing the following data in a text file

```
something
I
like
to
ride
horses
sometimes
its ok
```

However, in your application you want to have the following

string_A = `"something"`

string_B = `"I\nlike\nto\nride\nhorses\nsometimes"`

string_C = `"its ok"`

As you've already found, attempting to read the text file line by line will make it difficult to preserve the multi-line strings in your original data structure. One way to achieve this is to use a delimiter for your strings. Let's say the delimiter is the semi-colon character `;`. Then your text file could look like this:

```
something;
I
like
to
ride
horses
sometimes;
its ok;
```

Then you could define your read and write functions to use a delimiter when writing the data and parsing it:

```
public static void storeToFile(List<String> strings, String fileName, String delimiter = ";") {}
public static List<String> fromFile(String fileName, String delimiter = ";") {}
```

The storeToFile method would add the delimiter to the string when it is written to a file. The fromFile method would read up until encountering the delimiter instead of reading line by line.

This will help you preserve your original data.

> what if the user enters a string of characters that is also a separator

You could use a special character or non-printable character which helps avoid this situation, such as a null-byte (`delimiter = "\x00"`). You could also validate the strings ahead of time to ensure the delimiter is not within them. It helps to limit the text of your users to a pre-defined set of characters in these cases.

**Alternatives**

If you are looking for a quicker approach, you could also simply serialize your ArrayList when writing to a file and deserialize it when reading. However, this will cause artifacts of the serialization to be present in the text file and **it will not read as the following if you open the file**:

```
something
I
like
to
ride
horses
sometimes
its ok
```

Instead, you'll find metadata representing the ArrayList as a serialized entity.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the conventional end-of-line escape, a backslash or `\` character.

When writing the file, insert a `\` before each linefeed and backslash character in the user input. When reading the file, join lines that end with a backslash together into a single string, and replace any double-backslash sequences with a single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some lines of data, each embedded line terminator is escaped using double back slashes `\\`.  The trailing line terminator is kept to separate line groupings.

```
List<String> lines = List.of("To be or not to\\nbe that is the question.\n",
        "When in the course\\nof human events it becomes\\nnecessary...\n",
        "A single line");
```

write to a file

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("f:/Text.txt")) {
   for (String line : lines) {
       fw.write(line);
   }
    
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

read from the file and print

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("F:/Text.txt"))) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine().replace("\\n","\n");
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
    }
}  catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

prints

```
To be or not to
be that is the question.
-----------------------
When in the course
of human events it becomes
necessary...
-----------------------
A single line
-----------------------
```

Another way is to write the lines normally and then write a blank line a a delimiter.  When reading, just check if the line is blank and process accordingly.  Of course, this won't work if you want to include blank lines as embedded blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am looking for an idea on how to separate these strings in the file, I exclude the use of a separator, because what if the user enters a string of characters that is also a separator ..."*

It's not a difficult implementation.
Although, the use of the double-slash `\\` *would* be an optimal solution here.

Here is an example otherwise.

Utilize the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* method to divide the text on the new-line delimiter, and store each line within quotation marks on a single line, comma-delimited.

Additionally, assure to replace any `"` characters with `\"`.

```java
public static void storeToFile(List<String> strings, String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))) {
        for (String s : strings) w.println(parse(s));
        w.flush();
    }
}

static String parse(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (String ss : s.split("\\R")) {
        if (i++ != 0) sb.append(',');
        sb.append('"');
        sb.append(ss.replace("\"", "\\\""));
        sb.append('"');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And, when reading from the file, truncate the quotation marks, and *split* on a sequence of `","`.
As a note, the actual *regex* here is, `(?<!\\)\",\"`.

```java
public static List<List<String>> fromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
        List<List<String>> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        String s;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            s = sc.nextLine();
            s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
            strings.add(List.of(s.split("(?<!\\\\)\",\"")));
        }
        return strings;
    }
}
```

Example usage.

```java
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("something");
strings.add("I\nlike\nto\nride\nhorses\nsometimes");
strings.add("its ok");
storeToFile(strings, "file.txt");
List<List<String>> list = fromFile("file.txt");
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

file.txt

```
"something"
"I","like","to","ride","horses","sometimes"
"its ok"
```

Output

```
[something]
[I, like, to, ride, horses, sometimes]
[its ok]
```